# No decimal places in SwiftUI calculator for results

Tags: swift

I am just learning how to use swiftUI, and one of the projects i'm working on is a simple calculator. My only problem is when I try to do calculations that would have a decimal value (4/3, 8/9, etc.) the results only round up, and in cases where its 5/6 or 3/4, the result is always 0. I assume the problem is within this section of code, and if it's not i'd be happy to provide the rest. Thanks in advance!

```
func calculateResults() -> String
{
    if(validInput())
    {
        var workings = visibleWorkings.replacingOccurrences(of: "%", with: "*0.01")
        workings = workings.replacingOccurrences(of: "X", with: "*")
        let expression = NSExpression(format: workings)
        let result = expression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as! CGFloat
        return formatResult(val: result)
    }
    showAlert = true
    return ""
}
func validInput() -> Bool
{
    if(visibleWorkings.isEmpty)
    {
        return false
    }
    let last = String(visibleWorkings.last!)
    
    if(operators.contains(last) || last == "-")
    {
        if(last != "%" || visibleWorkings.count == 1)
        {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    return true
}

func formatResult(val : CGFloat) -> String
{
    if(val.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0)
    {
        return String(format: "%.0f", val)
    }
    
    return String(format: "%.2f", val)
}
```

Comment: What happens if you enter your expressions as "4.0/3.0" or "8.0/9.0" or "5.0/6.0" and "3.0/4.0"?  Have you been programming long?  Are you familiar with the difference between Integers and Floating point numbers and topics like Integer division?

Comment: If i add the decimal (8.0/9.0) it works correctly. Maybe I'm being picky but having to type in the ".0" for the right value to show up is tedious, but gets the job done. To answer your question, I've been using C++ for a little over 3 months, and this is my first time using xcode and swift. I know integers are whole numbers, floating point numbers include decimal places, but I don't have any knowledge on integer division.

Comment: OK... well 9/8 is dividing two integers (numbers without decimal points).  9.0/8.0 is dividing two floating point numbers (numbers with decimal points).  When you do 9/8 you get 1 with a remainder of 1, but the system will just throw away the remainder so 9/8 is 1.    9.0/8.0 is 1.125.  You might review a tutorial like https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/chap_01.html

Answer (score 0):

NSExpression is treating 5/6 as integer division.  In integer division, the remainder of any division is discarded.  So 5/6 would be 0 with a remainder of 6 (which is discarded) or just 0.

5.0/6.0 or even 5.0/6 will be done as floating point division.  This will yield a floating point result of 0.8333...

Google should be able to provide innumerable examples of integer vs. floating point division.

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift** you can use `Decimal.FormatStyle` with `.toNearestOrAwayFromZero` and `.significantDigits` like below:

```
import UIKit

var greeting = "Hello, playground"

let num_0: Decimal = 4/3
let num_1: Decimal = 8/9

let defaultStyle = Decimal.FormatStyle(locale: Locale(identifier: "en_US"))
let roundedStyle = defaultStyle.rounded(rule: .toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
let precisionStyle = roundedStyle.precision(.significantDigits(2))

print(num_0.formatted(precisionStyle))
print(num_1.formatted(precisionStyle))
```

[image]
Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal/formatstyle/3796436-rounded